# Changing Arcpy Message-Warning-Error Text Colors

Tags: arcpy, color

I recently came across a post about changing "[the default error color in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54623782/10859585)" and was interested in doing something similar with Arcpy's AddMessage, AddWarning, and/or AddError functions. A few older posts like [arcpy.AddMessage Formatting](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/arcpy-addmessage-formatting/td-p/35855) were made on Esri's site claiming that it's not possible, though they are quite a bit old.

Has there been any updates or workaround solutions?

I would assume that the message functions have some sort of html text coloring schema that they are following and are pulled from some file. Not sure if that comes from another python library, an OS setting, something Esri specifically built, etc.

If in fact AddMessage, AddWarning, AddError text color cannot be changed, would it be feasible to write a custom function or class that would be able to do this or is this a foundational issue with the processing dialog box?

Using ArcPy Pro.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do this using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro or ArcPy with ArcMap?  It may be the same answer for both but focusing on the former will be important when asking for an enhancement or lifting of a software limitation at ArcGIS Ideas.

Comment: ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro would be preferred. I'll update my post with that info.

Comment: I regularly develop python code to be run as script tools so use the messaging system that arcpy provides to write messages to the dialog box. I know of now way to alter the colour of the messages.

Comment: @Hornbydd sorry I am having a hard time reading your comment. Are you saying just print everything to the terminal and change the color there (like what Berend has answered below)? The print statements are necessarily for me, but others that are using the tool. So keeping everything in the Dialog box is preferred.

Comment: No I'm just agreeing with you. You have no control over the text colour when writing to the message dialog.

Comment: ESRI would have to have that defined somewhere though right? I guess they just have it locked up?

Comment: How should I proceed to mark a solution for this question, if there is none?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *where* you want to see colors, in a text editor, in the console, in ArcGIS desktop?

Some text editors support coloring based on text content, either native or with a plugin.

For consoles that support Ansi escape sequences, you could use those in the output. For instance, `arcpy.AddMessage("\u001B[31mRed\u001B[0m")` will output text in red.

[image: Red output text]

Comment: I'm looking for the ArcGIS process dialog box.